# I would like to make these edges "curve", any quick tips?

Tags: edges, geometry, bevel

Anyone know an easy way to make the edges where the tv screen meets the tv (see picture) smoother so it doesn't appear fake in a close up? Need to add points to round out the screen more but don't want to do it one by one.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In Edit mode, select the edge loop where the screen meets the TV, and set `Crease = 1.00`
2. then apply Subdivision Surface to the screen object

This allows Subdivision Surface to smooth out the object, while still keeping the base of the screen sharp

Comment: Got it! Thanks SampoK!!!